# How to make 5 year kid to sit and write

Tags: pre-schooler, homework

I have a 5 year old kid, he is pre-schooler. I am not able to make him sit and write his home work. He is very good in oral, but why he is not willing to write I don't know. How to make him write? He always wants to play with toys only.

Answer (score 1):

If he only plays with toys maybe you should transform the homework in a toy.

A magnetic whiteboard could help here but I don't really think it is necessary.
I don't have any precise examples here since I don't know what his homework is but I suppose it's nothing too crazy if he's/she's only .

I don't like writing either and I can understand him, if you're 5 you have other things to do than writing down some unmeaning letters and numbers.

Try to be creative, don't ask him to do his homework, prevent using the word homework, it can be hard but by finding a way to transform homework in a toy should work.